# codigniter how to make a drop down table from database values

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

I need to create a drop-down menu in Codigniter and the values will pulled from a database table. The data contains a group of movies, I need to be able to populate the data into the menu.

How should I do this?

Comment: Some code from what you've already tried would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

just iterate through your data and create a select list

```
<select name="movie_id">
  <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['name']; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

This will obviously be different based on your table schema

Answer (score 1):

According to Codeigniter documentation

see this url

[Code Igniter - form_dropdown selecting correct value from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331078/code-igniter-form-dropdown-selecting-correct-value-from-the-database)

[Codeigniter form_helper getting database rows to be values in select menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901703/codeigniter-form-helper-getting-database-rows-to-be-values-in-select-menu)

The first parameter will contain the name of the field, the second parameter will contain an associative array of options, and the third parameter will contain the value you wish to be selected. You can also pass an array of multiple items through the third parameter, and CodeIgniter will create a multiple select for you.

Your admin controller should have something like

```
$data['selected'] = $this->salary_expectation->get_salary_selected();
```

According to this, the admin view should be like this

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('salaries', $salaries, $selected_value);  ?>
```

Comment: my model//function shop_dropdown()
   {
    $this->db->select('shop'); //change this to the two main values you want to use
    $this->db->from('shop');
    //$this->db->where('category_online', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
     $data[$row['id']]=$row['name'];
    }
    return $data;

   }